# PHP + jQuery + Ajax form submission - return results on the same page

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, forms

I would like to have the following:

User submits a form by a click (`index.php`), the form input is processed by an external PHP file (`search.php`) and results are posted on the original page (`index.php`) in a div.

I have already got together most of the code. It submits a form on a click and sends it to a PHP script.

What I would need now is that the result from the PHP script are given back to the original page (`index.php`).

Here is my code so far:

```
function submit() {
    $(function() {
        var id = "id";
        var dataString = 'id=' + id;
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "inc/search.php",
            data: dataString,
            success: function() {
                goToByScroll("result");
                $('#result').html("<br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><
                                   div class='center'><img src='img/loader.gif' /></div>").hide().fadeIn(2500, function() {
                $('#result').html("Finished");
                });
            }
        });
        return false;
    });
}
```

My PHP file (for testing) is:

```
<?php function safe($value)
{
    htmlentities($value, ENT_QUOTES, 'utf-8');
    return $value;
}
if (isset($_POST['id'])) {
    $id = safe($_POST['id']);
    echo ($id);
}
elseif (!isset($_POST['id'])) {
    header('Location: error?id=notfound');
} ?>
```

I would like to have results from `search.php` (in this case "id") posted into #result, but I can't figure out how :S

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think you've got almost everything.  The callback function you have under `success` needs an argument which stands for the results from `search.php`

```
     success: function(res) {
             goToByScroll("result");
             $('#result').html("<br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><div class='center'><img src='img/loader.gif' /></div>").hide().fadeIn(2500, function() {
                 $('#result').html(res + "<br /><br /> Finished");
             });
         }
```

`res` is everything outputted be `search.php`.  Echo, stuff outside of php tags, etc  Anything you'd see if you loaded `search.php` itself.

I don't know if you wanted 'Finished' to still be there.  Take it out if you dont.

Comment: This is 100% working :) and the best thing: I have just had to copy and paste it! Thanks a lot!

Comment: hah i only added about six characters to yours you couldve just typed them.  glad it worked out

Answer (score 2):

Add a parameter to your success function, e.g.:

```
success: function(param) { ... }
```

The param is a string which is ALL of the output of your server side script.  You can set that to whatever you want it to be and place it inside some element

```
$("#element").html(param);
```

Comment: hi watcher, thanks for your quick reply and your time! i have just included my php test script. could you let me know what I have to add in the above example to display my results on index.php?

Comment: Whatever you echo in your server side php script will be set to the variable param in the success function.  Simply echo out the ID, if its not found just `echo("ID Not Found");`.  Then in the success function do: `$("#results").html(param);` and that should work.

Comment: Thanks a lot guys! I was almost at the solution when jon_darkstar came up with a, for me, easier solution! Thanks for ur time!!