# Submitting a form with Ajax and instantly displaying the results from a PHP file

Tags: php, jquery, html, ajax, forms

I know this has been covered so much but I'm a little out of my depth here and I just need someone to explain how to do this in a way I can understand.

I'm looking to submit an HTML form via the AJAX function in jQuery which then instantly sends the form data over to my PHP script. My PHP script then needs to gather that data and assign to variables etc. The PHP script then does a load of other crap and finally echos out some results based upon that data entered.

Once that's done, I want that echo'd data to appear on the same page as the HTML form.

What I don't understand is how to gather the response from the PHP file so that I can then output it on the form page.

I tried using the (res) argument that someone posted here: [PHP + jQuery + Ajax form submission - return results on the same page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5681594/php-jquery-ajax-form-submission-return-results-on-same-page) which from what I can see is along the right lines of what I'm trying to achieve but it was outputting the entire PHP file (the actual php code itself) and not my single echo.

Any help is much appreciated!

Thanks.

Comment: can you post your code this way we can see where the mistake is and help you correct it.

Comment: If you are getting the entire PHP file returned to you unprocessed then your interpreter might be broken. What happens when you plug in the URL of the PHP file directly into a browser? Does that also return the whole unprocessed PHP file?

Comment: It might be as simple as your php file has an html extension. Try hitting the PHP file directly and seeing what displays.

Comment: Your PHP script does have a .php extension I assume? Does this server normally process PHP files correctly?

Comment: which part are you having difficulty with: the get reaching the server, passing in the query parameters, executing the code on the server, getting the results back from the server, or displaying the retrieved text

Comment: Do you guys not read?
It said: but it was outputting the entire PHP file (the actual php code itself)

Comment: Is it crazy to think that perhaps the server doesn't have PHP installed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You simply need to set a `$.get()` or `$.post()` query.

Give the form an ID in your HTML:

```
<form id="ajaxquery" method="post" action="">
<label for="field">Type Something:</label>
<input type="text" name="field" id="field" value="" />
<input type="submit" value="Send to AJAX" />
</form>

<div id="success"></div>
```

Then in your JS:

```
$("#ajaxquery").live( "submit" , function(){
    // Intercept the form submission
    var formdata = $(this).serialize(); // Serialize all form data

    // Post data to your PHP processing script
    $.post( "/path/to/your.php", formdata, function( data ) {
        // Act upon the data returned, setting it to #success <div>
        $("#success").html ( data );
    });

    return false; // Prevent the form from actually submitting
});
```

Then in your PHP:

```
<?php

// Process form data
echo '<strong>You submitted to me:</strong><br/>';
print_r( $_REQUEST );
```

Anything echo()'d will be returned to the $.post() function as `data`

Comment: I understand how it works now! Thanks for posting this. Got my script working as well :)

Comment: works great but how do you make sure that the content in the text area is refreshed back to the default???

Answer (score 0):

Have an $.ajax(); call using jquery to submit the page and in success (when the PHP code runs) return json string and contain an element containing status:true or something like then call a function (in jquery success) which gets results from another php page and displays instantly

Answer (score 0):

[JQuery's get function](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.get/) will allow you to pass in a function that will be called on the requests on success.

```
jQuery.get( url [, data] [, success(data, textStatus, jqXHR)] [, dataType] )
```

Answer (score 0):

Anyway, if your actual code is fully displayed, there are few reasons I can think of:

A. Wrong server configuration/php compiler - your server can not process the php page as a script file and outputs it as a text.

B. Your code is written not correctly (mostly, when on the server short tags like `<?` are disabled and you need to write `<?php`) so your server does not accept this as a script.

Comment: Agreed sir, he seems to have a parsing problem.

Comment: Thanks for the quick responses everyone! I'll see if that fixes my issue. If not I'll post my code in here. Thanks :)