# Opening a url in a popup

Tags: javascript, php

How can I redirect my url below in a pop-up?

```
 $array[] = array ('id' => "$id", 'title' => "$evento", 'start' => "$dtevento2", 'end' => "$dtfim2", 'url' => "/eventos.php?id=$id", 'allDay' => "false");
```

I have the javascript code to the pop-up

```
<script language=javascript>
var win = null;
function NovaJanela(pagina,nome,w,h,scroll){
LeftPosition = (screen.width) ? (screen.width-w)/2 : 0;
TopPosition = (screen.height) ? (screen.height-h)/2 : 0;
settings = 'height='+h+',width='+w+',top='+TopPosition+',left='+LeftPosition+',scrollbars='+scroll+',resizable'
win = window.open(pagina,nome,settings);
}
</script>
```

And the link to use the code

```
<a href="eventos.php?id=<? echo $id; ?> "onclick="NovaJanela(this.href,'nomeJanela','620','500','no');return false">Open</a>
```

Comment: Excuse me, I don't understand, what you want. What is php url? How it differs from an ordinary url? What do you mean by saying: "redirect my url"?

Comment: Search on here for "AJAX" it's all you need. Lots of questions already answer this predicament. Here's one I answered that can help you get started: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7932460/submitting-a-form-with-ajax-and-instantly-displaying-the-results-from-a-php-file/7932555#7932555

Comment: I want that my URL described in my array open in a pop-up

Answer (score 0):

```
array('a' => 'Just' , 'b'=>'Persian Gulf');...
// output
// a='Just',b='Persian Gulf'...
```

did you mean it?

```
<?php
$array = array('a' => 'Just' , 'b'=>'Persian Gulf');
$keyy=array();
//
while(key($array)){
    array_push($keyy,key($array));
    next($array);
}
foreach($keyy as $ke)
echo $ke."='$array[$ke]' ,";
?>
```

Usable in All Places...

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
foreach($array as $arr){
?>
<a href="<?php print($arr['url']); ?>" onclick="NovaJanela(this.href,'nomeJanela','620','500','no');return false">Open</a>
<?php } ?>
```

I think you are looking for this. I hope you get an idea.